# How does a break in contributions (eg. working holiday) affect superannuation over time?

Tags: compound-interest, superannuation

I'd like to better understand how a break in superannuation contributions during a working holiday affects the long term balance.

Say I'm 35 years old and accumulated $100,000 AUD in Australian superannuation. I wish to retire by 67 and my yearly income is $90,000 AUD. I have calculated my superannuation balance will be $408,327 AUD when I reach 67.

[image]

I'm planning to live and work in Germany for the next 3 years (until 38 years old) where I'll be making no contributions to my superannuation, but instead contributions to the German equivalent of a superannuation fund. 2 years after I've returned to Australia (40 years old) I'm eligible to transfer my German pension to an Australian bank account.

How would the scenario of not contributing over 3 years affect my superannuation balance in the long run? Also, would it be worth me re-investing my German pension once received? Any other advice much appreciated.